# Media Queries in DotNetNuke, mobile enablement

Tags: dotnetnuke, media-queries

I am starting a new project which requires content managment and have decided to use dotnetnuke which I have never used before and a concern of mine is the use of media queries for mobile devices.

Can I use media queries in a dotnetnuke skin and does anyone have any examples / tutorials of this in use? I have looked everywhere and cant find any information of dotnetnuke utilizing media queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [free skin available on the DotNetNuke Store](http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-details/51degreesmobi---free-mobile-skin) that demonstrates some mobile skinning concepts.  But, ultimately, you should be able to include media queries in your skin's stylesheet without doing anything special.  Is there something specific that you're running up against?

You'll probably want to include a `viewport` `<meta>` tag, which you can do like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Meta" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Meta.ascx" %> 
<dnn:Meta runat="server" Name="viewport" Content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Thanks in the end i just tested Media queries in skin.css and it worked.